# Spring Security upgrade from 3.0.0.RELEASE to 3.1.0.RELEASE - No longer storing the SecurityContext to the HttpSession when authentication is null

Tags: spring-security

In our application if an account is locked a message is displayed to the user on the login page. The message can vary according to some settings related to the user (which are fetched from the database) that are stored in the Context. So on the login page we have

```
AgentProfile agentProfile = ((WUSecurityContext) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()).getAgentProfile();
```

With Spring Security 3.0.0.RELEASE this approach worked. The user attempted to login, the LockedException was thrown, the authentication in the Context was set to null and the SecurityContext was stored in the HttpSession.

Here is the code from *HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository* version 3.0.0.RELEASE

```
    void saveContext(SecurityContext context) {
        if(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.this.authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(context.getAuthentication())) {
            if(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.this.logger.debug("SecurityContext contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. ");
            }

        } else {
            HttpSession httpSession = this.request.getSession(false);
            if(httpSession == null) {
                httpSession = this.createNewSessionIfAllowed(context);
            }

            if(httpSession != null && context.hashCode() != this.contextHashBeforeChainExecution) {
                httpSession.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", context);
                if(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.this.logger.debug("SecurityContext stored to HttpSession: \'" + context + "\'");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

However the code in saveContext changed and now includes a check to see if the authentication is null (*if(authentication != null &&*...) which prevents the SecurityContext from being stored in the HttpSession

*HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository* version 3.1.0.RELEASE

```
   protected void saveContext(SecurityContext context) {
        Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
        HttpSession httpSession = this.request.getSession(false);
        if(authentication != null && !HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.this.authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication)) {
            if(httpSession == null) {
                httpSession = this.createNewSessionIfAllowed(context);
            }

            if(httpSession != null && (this.contextChanged(context) || httpSession.getAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.this.springSecurityContextKey) == null)) {
                httpSession.setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.this.springSecurityContextKey, context);
                if(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.this.logger.debug("SecurityContext stored to HttpSession: \'" + context + "\'");
                }
            }

        } else {
            if(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.this.logger.debug("SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.");
            }

            if(httpSession != null) {
                httpSession.removeAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.this.springSecurityContextKey);
            }

        }
    }
```

I am not sure what to do about this. Trying to override this and make it work like it did in version 3.0.0.RELEASE feels like it is probably the wrong thing to do. But if I do not have the users information available in the Context on the log in page then how will I display a custom message? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353262/spring-security-documentation-for-spring-security-last-exception. You can save your information into session in a custom handler.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion.  I am not sure if I fully understand how this helps me but this is one thing I know I can do and it will work. I already have a custom AuthFailureHandler so within onAuthenticationFailure I can add "httpSession.setAttribute("AGENT_PROFILE", xyz.getAgentProfile());" Now on my Login page I can use "requestGlobals.getHTTPServletRequest().getSession().getAttribute("AGENT_PROFILE");" Is this what you were thinking..?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea in the linked question/answer. Or better, you pass it as a query parameter within your custom handler.